# SonicWall blocks from others computers in the local network

Tags: vpn

Sometimes I have to connect to my office using SonicWall VPN (version 4.9).
When VPN is open, I can't access any of local computers/printers in the network.
My local network is 192.168.2.0/24, and this is my route table without VPN:

`IPv4 Route Table
= = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = =
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.2.1    192.168.2.168     20
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
      192.168.2.0    255.255.255.0         On-link     192.168.2.168    276
    192.168.2.168  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.2.168    276
    192.168.2.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.2.168    276
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link     192.168.2.168    276
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.2.168    276
= = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = =
Persistent Routes:
  None`

But when I open VPN, my route table is:

`IPv4 Route Table
= = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = =
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.2.1    192.168.2.168     21
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0         On-link       10.160.0.56      2
       10.0.0.120  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.160.0.56      2
       10.120.1.2  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.160.0.56      2
       10.160.0.0    255.255.254.0         On-link       10.160.0.56    257
      10.160.0.56  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.160.0.56    257
     10.160.1.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.160.0.56    257
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
      192.168.2.0    255.255.255.0         On-link     192.168.2.168    276
    192.168.2.168  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.2.168    276
    192.168.2.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.2.168    276
    204.9.165.163  255.255.255.255      192.168.2.1    192.168.2.168     20
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link     192.168.2.168    276
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link       10.160.0.56    257 
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306 
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.2.168    276 
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.160.0.56    257 
= = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = =
Persistent Routes:
  None`

What rule in the second table makes that? What exact command should I use to delete the problematic rule?
Please help. TIA!

Answer (score 0):

It's the VPN client.  Your admin can configure the VPN to route all traffic via the VPN tunnel.

Specifically, the metric for the VPN gateway is lower than the regular LAN:

```
IPv4 Route Table
= = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = =
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.2.1    192.168.2.168     21 <-----
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0         On-link       10.160.0.56      2 <-----
```

Comment: So do I need to delete: [0.0.0.0,0.0.0.0,On-link,10.160.0.56]
to see computers in local network? If yes - what is the exact command? Or maybe I can change the metric? If yes - what is the exact command?